# Annotation Aggregation

Tags: java, annotations, duplicates, aggregation

I have multiple classes where I have always the same annotations over the fields that define the primary key of the table  for example:

```
@Id 
@Type(type = "uuid-binary")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2", 
parameters = { @Parameter(
        name = "uuid_gen_strategy_class", 
        value = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerationStrategy") 
})
@Column(name="PROFILE_ID", unique = true)
@NotNull(message = "we have one message" , payload =Severity.Info.class)
private UUID profileId;
```

Now I am looking for a way to aggregate all those annotations to one single annotation something like annotation aggregation when I do validation i.e.
I can aggregate the @NotNull and @Size from (javax.validation.constraints
)  to the following annotation called “Name”.

```
 package org.StudentLib.CustomeAnnotations;
 import …
 @Target( {FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
 @Retention(RUNTIME)
 @Constraint(validatedBy = {})
 @Documented
 @NotNull
 @Id 
 @Size(message = "The size of the name should be between {min} and {max} caracters", 
                min = 1, max = 50, 
                payload = Severity.Info.class
                )
 public @interface Name {
    }
```

So how do I do the same for persistent annotations,  I always get

> The annotation @Id is disallowed for this location

Why I am getting this error?  Is there a way to combine the persistence annotations and validation annotation in one single annotation.  The reason I am asking this is because I have around 40 tables( Entities ) in my code and I feel that I am dong code duplication every time I need to define the primary key of that table.

Comment: How is the `@Id` annotation defined? Note that `@Id` at `Name` is used on a type, while `@Id` at `profileId` is used on a field. This is a difference for the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because the `Target` meta-annotation applied to the `Id` annotation type doesn't contain the parameters `ANNOTATION_TYPE` in its value field.  Take a look at the [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Id.html), and you will see it (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> '@Target').

The [`@Target`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html) meta-annotation describes to what java language constructs an annotation can be applied.  Due to the fact that you are unable to apply this annotation to an `ANNOTATION_TYPE`, you will be unable to create such a shortcut annotation.

As a side note, you can see by looking at this javadoc, that `@Target` has a `@Target` of `{ANNOTATION_TYPE}`, which is effectively what makes an annotation a meta-annotation.